# How to intercept and modify mic audio stream Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, audio, microphone, recording

I am looking for a way I can modify an output stream from the microphone.

The idea is to modify the output stream merging two audio streams into single one.

My use case is the following. When a person makes a skype call it adds a background song to the output stream.

Is there any way to do this for Windows ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about manipulating the input that other programs see this would be fairly difficult to implement, you would have to create a virtual audio device and then have the target program use that. There are existig packages that already provide that functionality, however, perhaps a search for "virtual audio cable" or "virtual mixer" would come up with something that would work.